# zoom in and zoom out in ng2-pdf-viewer

Tags: angular, pdf

am using ng2-pdf-viewer to show pdf files in my app.

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc"
          [page]="page"
          [zoom]="1.1"
          style="width: 100%;"
```

> 

I want to add zoom in and zoom out buttons. How can i implement this in ng2-pdf-viewer.

Suggestion about any other better library that i can use with angular 4 for pdf files will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I implemented custom zoom in and zoom out button by changing `[zoom]` property of ng2 pdf-viewer

html

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc"
                [page]="page"
                [original-size]="true"
                [zoom]="zoom_to"></pdf-viewer>
```

and here is zoom methods in components class

```
zoom_in() {
    this.zoom_to = this.zoom_to + 0.25;
  }

  zoom_out() {
    if (this.zoom_to > 1) {
       this.zoom_to = this.zoom_to - 0.25;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

put a simple one thing. easily working. have fun!!!

//html part

```
<pdf-viewer [fit-to-page]="fitToPage" [(page)]="pageVariable" [zoom]="zoom" [autoresize]="autoresize" [show-all]="showAll" [src]="pdfSrc" [render-text]="true" style="display: block"></pdf-viewer>
    <button ion-button (click)="incrementZoom(-0.1)">
      <img src="assets/Zoom_Out.png"/>
    </button>
    <button ion-button (click)="incrementZoom(0.1)">
      <img src="assets/Zoom_in.png"/>
    </button>
```

//ts part, it will automatically change the size.

```
zoom: number = 1.0;
originalSize: boolean = true;

incrementZoom(amount: number) {
    this.zoom += amount;   }
```